# Subscribing to G-suite fail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, domain

I've tried to subscribe to g-suite, but for now it isn't going succesfully.

During the process I choose a domain that costs 7$ per year, I've already registered a mail with the choosen domain while i was subscribing to g-suite.

Am I obligated to pay for that domain or no?

Sorry if the question is dumb or generic but I'm not understanding what to do

Answer (score 1):

Of course, G-Suite doesn't includes a domain, you must have one and use (and pay each monnth) G-Suite por each email account.

Comment: Can i unsubscribe from this payment?

Comment: Sure, yo can cancel G-Suite at any moment, please read:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/1257646?hl=en